Structure and Subgroup Structure of $Aut(SL(2, 2^f))$
I am doing research involving the family of groups $SL(2, 2^f)$ for a prime $f\geq 5$ where the order of $SL(2, 2^f)$ divisible by exactly 4 primes $2, 3, p$ and $q$ such that $q = 2^f – 1$ and $3p = 2^f + 1$. It is known that $Aut(SL(2, 2^f))\cong\mathbb{Z}_f\ltimes SL(2, 2^f)$. Is the subgroup structure of $Aut(SL(2, 2^f))$ known? More specifically, is it known if there are elements of order $qf$ or $pf$ in $Aut(SL(2, 2^f))$? The $p$- and $q$- Sylow subgroups of $SL(2, 2^f)$ are known to be cyclic.

The centralizer of an element of order $f$ is ${\rm SL}(2,2)$, so it is clear that there are no elements of orders $fp$ or $fq$.
Alternatively you could just consider the natural action of ${\rm\Gamma L}(2,2^f)$ on $2^f+1$ points. An element of order $q$ is a single $q$-cycle and a fixed point, whereas an element of order $p$ is $3$ $p$-cycles, so they could not be centralized by an element of order $f$.

Thank you, this helps a lot!

Derek Holt has answered your question about element orders.
I'm not sure if the subgroup structure of $Aut(PSL(2,q))$ has been written down in general, but:

The subgroup structure of $PSL(2,q)$ is known, this goes back to Dickson. See for example this question.
The maximal subgroups of $X$ for all $PSL(2,q) \leq X \leq Aut(PSL(2,q))$ are known. This is in the maximal subgroups book by Bray, Holt, Roney-Dougal; also this preprint by Giudici.

Now let $L = SL(2,2^f) = PSL(2,2^f)$ and $A = Aut(L)$.
If $H \leq Aut(L)$, then $H \cap L \trianglelefteq H \leq N_A(H \cap L)$.
You are assuming that $f$ is a prime, so either $H = H \cap L$ or $H = N_A(H \cap L)$. Here the possibilities for $H \cap L$ are known by Dickson.
